# How to Build a Decision tree Regressor model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am learning ML and was doing a simple handsOn as below:

//
Split boston.data into two sets names x_train and x_test. Also, split boston.target into two sets y_train and y_test.

Build a Decision tree Regressor model from x_train set, with default parameters. 
//

I did following code for this:

```
from sklearn import datasets, model_selection, tree

boston = datasets.load_boston()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(boston.data,boston.target, random_state=30)

dt  = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()

dt_reg = dt.fit(x_train)
```

When I am doing above, it's giving:

```
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Can I fit a model for one training dataset?

What should I give here as 'y'?

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, the `fit()` method takes 2 parameters for a regression problem, the predictors and the outcome:

```
dt_reg = dt.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Supervised learning models such as the regression tree you are using require a set of observations composed of features (each row of `X_train` can be understood as a vector containing features for one observation) and a target outcome (each element in the vector `y_train`)

Comment: ok...thanks.
The Problem (HandOn)  I was solving  is as below:

"Build a Decision tree Regressor model from x_train set, with default parameters.", 


Means, we cannot make Regressor on one set. This should be x_train and y_train?

Comment: Yes, `X` and `y` here are part of the same "set" of observations.