# Build Decision Tree Regression Model and predicting output from sample - Machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am new to Machine Learning . When i am practicing Decision tree regression model with default parameters using boston data set from scikit-learn module.

After this link solution([How to Build a Decision tree Regressor model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150132/how-to-build-a-decision-tree-regressor-model)), i printed model accuracy on training data set with

```
print(dt_reg.score(X_train,Y_train)))
print(dt_reg.score(X_test,Y_test)))
```

Now, im facing issue with : ***print the Predicted housing price for first two samples of X_test set***. For this , i wrote like below, but not getting correct output. Could you please help me to predict first 2 sample of X_test dataset.

```
predicted = dt_reg.predict(X_test)

for i in range(2):
    print("Predict housing price",predicted[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

For demonstration purposes, let's see the full code. Say you train your regression model like this:

```py
from sklearn import datasets, model_selection, tree

boston = datasets.load_boston()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(boston.data,boston.target, random_state=30)

dt  = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()

dt_reg = dt.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Now print the `train` and `test` scores:

```py
print(dt_reg.score(x_train, y_train))
print(dt_reg.score(x_test, y_test))
```

```
>> 1.0
>> 0.5826465689845075
```

Let's see how the prediction on test data looks like:

```py
predicted = dt_reg.predict(x_test)
print(predicted)
```

```py
>> array([18.2, 12.8, 20.1, 30.1, 14.5, .....])
```

Now select and print the output of prediction on the first two test samples:

```py
for i in predicted[:2]:
    print(i)
```

```py
>> 18.2
>> 12.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like as follows:

I assume that you wrote this code firstly,

```
from sklearn import datasets, model_selection, tree

boston = datasets.load_boston()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(boston.data,boston.target, random_state=30)

dt  = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()

dt_reg = dt.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

and then put the predicted y values in y_pred variable as follows:

```
y_pred = dt_reg.predict(X_test)
```

and finally, you can write it using:

```
y_pred[0:n]
```

n shows the number of results that you want to show. Put 2 instead of "n"